# How did Han and Chewie find the Falcon?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Was there a clue to how Han and Chewie just happened to be in the same neighborhood as the Falcon as it was escaping Jakku? Was it just a coincidence? They were on a merchant mission to deliver Rathtars so its not like they were actively looking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the novelization, they just happened to be in the same general vicinity.

Han explains that the Falcon had a beacon that turned on with the ship, and that they detected the beacon.

> Looking away from them for the first time since they had emerged from below, their captor addressed his towering cohort. “Told ya we should’ve double-checked the Western Reaches! Just lucky we were in the general vicinity when the ship powered up and its beacon snapped on.”

Comment: Of course, Obi-Wan would have told him that there is no such thing as luck.

Comment: @JakeGould Obi-Wan likely would have told Han that the Force somehow pulled him to the system, since there's no such thing as luck.

Comment: One thing though is that Han was surprised the falcon was on Jakku when Rey told him that....... although they never had left the Jakku System and still were in it........

Comment: @Thomas no, the Falcon had gone through multiple owners over the years since Han lost it, and has been on Jakku for quite a while. Han and Chewie have not been in that area the whole time.